# Can't get populate() to fill out array in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Let me begin by saying I know that this seems to be a frequently asked question and I've spent a couple of days trying to figure it out but no answer seems to work so I'm trying on here.

I have two models, *User* and *Chapter*: a *Chapter* can have have many members (*Users*). When I do `router.get('/chapters')` I want to see an array of all the *Users* associated with a *Chapter* as a property along with the other *Chapter* properties, like so:

```
[
    {
        "leads": [],
        "members": [
           {"_id":"someString1","firstName":"...", "lastName":"..."},
           {"_id":"someString2","firstName":"...", "lastName":"..."},
        ],
        "date": "2018-12-12T15:24:45.877Z",
        "_id": "5c11283d7d13687e60c186b3",
        "country": "5c11283d7d13687e60c185d6",
        "city": "Buckridgestad",
        "twitterURL": "qui",
        "bannerPic": "http://lorempixel.com/640/480/people",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

But what I'm getting is this:

```
  [
        {
            "leads": [],
            "members": [],
            "date": "2018-12-12T15:24:45.877Z",
            "_id": "5c11283d7d13687e60c186b3",
            "country": "5c11283d7d13687e60c185d6",
            "city": "Buckridgestad",
            "twitterURL": "qui",
            "bannerPic": "http://lorempixel.com/640/480/people",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
```

These are my Schemas:

**Chapter**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const ChapterSchema = new Schema({
  country: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "countries"
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  leads: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "users"
    }
  ],
  members: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "users"
    }
  ],
  twitterURL: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  bannerPic: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
});

module.exports = Chapter = mongoose.model("chapters", ChapterSchema);
```

**User**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  organisation: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  chapter: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "chapters"
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  admin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  lead: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

Like I said, when I call the endpoint, I want it to return me all the *Chapters* with all the *Users* as a populated property.

I've tried a lot of variations of **.populate()** but to know luck. The closest I got was going through the early levels of callback hell which I know isn't necessary with today's tech, but nothing is working!

My **routes/api/chapters.js**

```
// @route    GET api/chapters
// @desc     Get all Chapters
// @access   Public

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Chapter.find()
    .populate("members")
    .then(chapters => {
      return res.json(chapters);
    })
    .catch(err =>
      res.status(404).json({ nochaptersfound: "No Chapters found" })
    );
});
```

I can get it to work the other way around:

My **routes/api/users.js**

```
// @route    GET api/users
// @desc     Return all users
// @access   Public

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  User.find()
    .populate("chapter")
    .exec()
    .then(users => res.status(200).json(users))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Returns a user with the populated *Chapter*, but I can't populate the **chapter.members** array

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure chapters have members? Have you looked into it to see if it was saved correctly? If you dont populate, does it comes with multiple ids?

Comment: yes, when I call /api/users, each user has a chapter ID which corresponds to correctly saved chapters (I use postman and can search both collections)

Comment: No, what I want to know is if chapter is storing the members. From your answer, I'm assuming you are not saving the members to the chapters, you might be assuming that mongoose is doing that for you, but it isnt

Comment: Users saving chapters doesnt mean chapter will automatically have users

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I believe you are not actually storing users in your chapters. What you are doing is this:

```
User.create({..., chapter: id})...
```

And assuming chapter now has a user. Its not the way it works with mongoose, so if you want to actually save in both place, you will need to do it yourself. You are thinking about this as if it were a relational database

You will need to do something like:

```
const user = await User.create({..., chapter: id})
const chapter = await Chapter.findOne({ _id: id })
chapter.members.push(user)
chapter.save()
```

If your populate wasn't working, you'd not get an empty array, you'd get an array with ids. Your current populate query is fine, you just don't have any data to populate

With promises, it would look like this:

```
var userPromise = User.create({..., chapter: id}).exec()
var chapterPromise = Chapter.findOne({ _id: id }).exec()
Promise.all([userPromise, chapterPromise]).then((user, chapter) => {
  chapter.members.push(user)
  return chapter.save()
}).then(chapter => {
  // send response
})
```

If you need 10 chapters with 10 to 50 users, I'd create 50 users, then push all of them into the chapters and save the chapter.

Comment: Ok I see - you're right, I am thinking about this too much like a relational database. I'm trying to seed data (10 chapters with between 10-50 users in each chapter), though which is where I think the issue is coming from. Asynchronicity is pretty confusing. I'll try adjusting my seed file to using Async Await

Comment: Still not getting anywhere :-( Can you give me and idea of how you (as novice me) would structure a seed file that would generate 10 chapters, each with 30-50 members (users) each please?

Comment: @JJMcGregor i'll update my code to show it with promises

Comment: Does the user really need to have a chapter on its document btw?

Comment: Thanks so much for this - I'll try it out when I get home in a few hours :-)

Comment: Still not working :-( I'm confused as to where and how the chapterPromise and userPromise work together - where does the id come from? Do I need to run them in a loop? Sorry, but I find NoSQL very confusing. I also forgot to mention that user.chapter is required, so you can't create a user without a chapter ref

Comment: Ok, so do the other way around. Create a chapter, then create 50 users with reference to that chapter, and then get all these users and update your chapter to include them. `chapter.members = arrayOfUsers` then chapter.save()

Comment: yeah this isn't going well. This mix of loops, promises and population is killing me.